# When trying to enter in a question mark into adb shell it shows up as a d, why is this?

Tags: android, shell, command, adb

So I am trying to enter in the question mark character `?`, and when I use the command `adb shell input text ?` it shows up as a `d` in current text field. However, if I do the command `adb shell input text \?` the question mark shows up, but with the `\` in front of it (`\?`). Is there a way to fix this? No other characters are having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Within the *nix verse, the question mark is a wildcard that matches exactly one character. This means it will need to be escaped if you want to use the `?` character instead of the wildcard feature. Why it's giving you a `d` and not an error is a little beyond me.

`adb shell input text "?"` or `adb shell input text \?` should both work.

http://www.linfo.org/wildcard.html

Comment: "?" gives a d, and \? gives "\?", I want only the question mark.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
adb shell input text \\?
```

That should work.